# navigationBar of UIPrintInteractionController and UIAppearance

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiappearance

I use `UIAppearance` to set backgroundImage of all `NavigationBar`s in my app.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

At the same time I use `UIPrintInteractionController` to implement a printing feature.

The problem is that printing dialog uses global appearance setting for it's navigation bar. 
It looks like this:

[image]

In this dialog it's not appropriately, I would like to not to use any background images here and have a system dialog.

I tried to use 
`[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPrintInteractionController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];`
, but app crashes with this message: `UIPrintInteractionController does not conform to the UIAppearanceContainer protocol`.

The second idea was to set the backgroundImage of navigationBar to nil for `UIPrintInteractionController`, for example when it gets initialized, or before it is shown (in delegate method). But `UIPrintInteractionController` has no public methods to get it's navigationBar, and moreover, it inherits from `NSObject`.

Is there a way to get rid of background image in navigation bar of `UIPrintInteractionController`?

Comment: Try using: <!-- language: objective-c --> [UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPopoverController class], nil]

Comment: @robert.wijas Thanks, it works. I'll accept it if you post it as answer.

Comment: I did that but someone converted it to a comment. Posting again as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that this controller is presented in UIPopoverController which supports UIAppearance containment:

```c
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPopoverController class], nil]
```

Comment: Tried and it doesn't work: [[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIPopoverController class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];